# Using the Oracle database parser from Java using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm writing a tool in Java which submits statements to a database, which are later run. I'm using JDBC to connect to the database. The database is Oracle 10g.

Before the statements are written to the database I want to parse them to check when they run later there will be no problems. I looked into using an ANTLR solution to this as there are grammars available, but surely If I have a connection to the database there must be a way to use the databases built in parser.

So essentially my question is:

Is there a way using JDBC I can make a call to the database parser passing it an SQL statement and it will return me some sort of feedback, telling me if it was successful or any error messages?

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Many thanks.

Edit:

Using connection.prepareStatement does not seem to work for instance this outputs parsed successfully!

```
String statement = "WHERE DISTINCT SELECT";
    Connection connection;
    try {
        connection = this.controller.getDataSource().getConnection();
        connection.prepareStatement(statement);
        connection.close();
        mainPanel.setPositiveText("Parsed Successfully!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mainPanel.setNegativeText("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
```

The soultion I used is as follows:

```
    String statement = "DECLARE "
            + "myNumber NUMBER; "
            + "BEGIN "
            + "myNumber := SYS.dbms_sql.open_cursor; "
            + "SYS.DBMS_SQL.PARSE(myNumber, '" + text + "', SYS.DBMS_SQL.NATIVE); "
            + "END;";

    Connection connection;
    try {
        connection = this.controller.getDataSource().getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(statement);
        preparedStatement.execute();
        connection.close();
        mainPanel.setPositiveText("Parsed Successfully!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mainPanel.setNegativeText("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
```

Comment: The Statement execQuery or execUpdate methods will throw the exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no idea what exactly do you want to achiveve but maybe yo migh try to use package `DBMS_SQL` and it's method `PARSE`. This works only with *DML*  statements only. This is what Oracle SQL Developer does.

This [parser](https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser) might be used for DML statements too. For PL/SQL it will need some tweaking. As far as I know nobody spent enough time to create a real fully validating parser for Oracle's DDL.

[Here](https://sourceforge.net/p/tora/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/tora/src/tools/toworksheet.cpp#l145) is an example how I use it:

```
declare 
 l_cursor number := dbms_sql.open_cursor; 
 l_offset number := -1 ; 
begin 
  begin 
    dbms_sql.parse( l_cursor, :st, dbms_sql.native ); 
  exception when others then
   l_offset := dbms_sql.last_error_position;
  end;
dbms_sql.close_cursor( l_cursor );
  :off := l_offset;
end;
```

Simply execute this block. Pass one input parameter of type VARCHAR2(String) (max 32KB) and one output parameter NUMBER.

Comment: Hi Ivan, dbms_sql.parse seems exactly like what I need. Could you give me a small example of its usage please? I want any variables used to be temporary, there should be nothing left behind in the database after the statements are executed.

Comment: Can this be used with jdbc , I believe we need to do execute(). SO, will it help?

Comment: You have to executed if with JDBC as an anonymous PL/SQL block.

Comment: Beware you really should call `dbms_sql.close_cursor( l_cursor );` in the PL/SQL block. Otherwise you will leak resources on DB server side. (See DB paramater `OPEN_CURSORS`)

Answer (score 1):

Without executing the Query, your cannot get a feedback(or resultset, about it. `Connection.preparedStatement` just return you a `PreparedStatement` object, which is just a handler.

`PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` is only what executes the query actually, pushing to the database.