# How can I validate SQL query syntax in oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
set NOEXEC ON;
Select * from emp;
Set NOEXEC OFF;
```

This validation is working in SQL Server. But It's not working in oracle.

Is there any syntax to check the query is valid or not in Oracle.

Comment: Why?  What problem are you trying to solve that causes you to want to check the syntax without executing the query?  It's possible that you want your client application to prepare the statement without executing it (or to use `dbms_sql.prepare`) but that would execute DDL statements.

Comment: more information about dbms_sql.prepare. (Possible duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745010/using-the-oracle-database-parser-from-java-using-jdbc/20745645#20745645

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using [`EXPLAIN PLAN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231)

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT FROM emp;
```

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00936: missing expression

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM emp;
```

> Explained

Comment: In my worksheet PLAN is underlined as a mistake and I get an error when I run the command: 
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword".

Comment: So what's the question in here? You are missing some keyword in your query.

Comment: Does this work only for select and not for alter queries?