# VBA: Validate SQL Code

Tags: sql, oracle, vba, validation, excel

Is it possible to validate a SQL code on syntax correctness with VBA?

In my scenario, the user is entering a SQL Statement into a text box of a user form. I would first like to validate if the SQL statement is correct syntax wise, and second check if it's a SELECT statement.

**What the validation shall check**

- Are the SQL keywords (which can be used in a SELECT statement) spelled correct
- Order of SQL keywords
- Is the statement a SELECT statement

**Summarizing the comments**

- The RDBMS is Oracle
- The Excel sheet does not have a connection to the Oracle database.
- The Excel sheet will be uploaded to a system, then the SQL codes will be executed on the database.
- I am aware of the possibility of SQL injection.
- The provided SQL statement shall be checked on syntax correctness. Column names shall not be checked, as database structure is not known.

Comment: In SQL Server (please tag the actual RDBMS - Oracle, MySQL,???) you can issue a `SET NOEXEC ON`, run it, and catch any error

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. It's a Oracle RDBMS. I do not have any connection to the database.

Comment: Here's one way that I came up with after 2 minutes of searching. It's far more complicated that SQL Server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745010/using-the-oracle-database-parser-from-java-using-jdbc/20745645#20745645. I should warn you against doing this. A user can type `DROP TABLE schema.table` and it will drop a table. Or they can run a cross join that makes the server run out of temp space.

Comment: The thing is, it'll throw an error anyway. Why do you need to check it first?

Comment: Because there will be several statements, and I do want to pre validate the statements before they will get executed.

Comment: Little Bobby Tables is watching you. As Nick.McDermaid says this looks like an open invitation to SQL injection

Comment: Yes and I am aware of it. However, I still want to check whether the provided statement is sytnax wise correct.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - put that in as an full-sized answer: it is both correct and useful. We'll  need an Oracle Dev to swing by and tell us where the equivalent to `NOEXEC` exists in PL-SQL - and they are notorious for only answering questions if you provide exactly the right wording, which kinda defeats the point here - but the essential answer is that you make the RDBMS parse SQL, rather than trying to do it yourself: and that, in turn, might introduce an inexperienced coder to a very important principle in programming: NEVER, EVER, WRITE A PARSER TO DO A JOB THAT AN EXISTING PARSER CAN DO.

Comment: I am looking for a solution in excel vba. I do not have a db connection.

Comment: What are you going to do with the SQL once you've validated it with your external validator if you don't have a DB?

Comment: It will be uploaded to the database system, then sql statements will be executed. That's the reason why I would like to inform the user prior to this upload whether the SQL is correct or not.

Comment: This is an odd task, but others have voiced their reservations so no need for me to repeat them - even though I share them. I think at the very least I would create a dummy database with all relevant tables and fields and run the SQL text against that. If the command threw an error you could catch it and return `False`. I might even do a table and row count to warn of deletes or drops. If you wanted actually to parse and highlight the source of the syntax error in VBA then maybe heed the above advice.

Comment: If you don't have the schema of the database you are uploading to then you could have a misspelt or missing column in your select and it will fail. There's no way to externally validate this without an up to date schema.

Comment: I see. Besides, some validation can be done anyway.

Comment: I don't think I can help any further but good luck

Comment: This is old, but if you could clone the DB schema (not necessarily all/any of the data) once a day/week to a server/location that you do have access to, you could create a connection to that, throw some queries at it and create some errors that way. Just a thought.